# I have disabled products in magento which are showing 404 not found crawling error

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I have disabled products in magento which are showing 404 not found crawling error,I want to remove this crawling errors for seo

Comment: You have other SEO issues that are more useful to pursue than 404 per Google => http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html

Answer (score 1):

When you try to visit disabled product in Magento then it shows 404 error. In order to open product details correctly you must mark product as enabled.

Answer (score 0):

just update your latest sitemap and submit it to google. Google take some time to update your sitemap till sitemap not update you can use redirect disabled product url to home page url.

Comment: how to redirect disabled product url to home page url.

Comment: using htaccess for example
`Redirect http://example.com/product1.html http://example.com`

Comment: but there are 1000s of product disabled,no any other option

Comment: By Updating Sitemap,google won't search disabled products?

Comment: you can use regular expression in htaccess so your problem solve.

Comment: Yep, there are thousands, let Google figure it out, and Google figures it out by trying all non-backlinked pages until it realizes they aren't coming back. As to updating sitemap, don't you have that turned on in Magento? Sitemaps only tell Google what pages are active. You're trying to create for yourself a management nightmare, running around trying to figure out the multiple rewrite rules to redirect pages. You have other SEO issues that are more useful to pursue than 404 per Google => http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html

Comment: once you submit your sitemap to google then google understand which link are available in your site and it update i think 24 hours. Please submit latest sitemap on google. Magento include link of your product page, static page by default. You can generate site map at **Catalog >> Google Sitemap** and generate sitemap. once you update sitemap in google, you no need to redirect for those link.

Comment: Catalog>>Google Sitemap i have enabled it yesterday with time 6.30,so how to check if it is working or not???

Comment: please tell me your site url I'll check it for you.

Comment: It will create a new sitemap datestamped at the time you set for it to create in the location you entered in the configuration. Check for file date change for a couple days, if it's changing, it's being updated.